# "Dynamic" rewrite with mod_rewrite and apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl

I´ve a bit of a "strategic" problem with creating a nice mod_rewrite solution for a shop. The shop has **different kind of pages**:

- Products (products.php)
- Categories (category.php)
- Content (content.php)

So the **"default" URI´s look like this**:

- /products.php?id=2
- /category.php?id=4
- /content.php?id=5

The final result should be a URI´s that include the name of the page (product name, category name).

- /chocholate-icecream -> product.php?id=2
- /coffe-and-ice -> category.php?id=4
- /imprint -> content.php?id=5

My problem now is, that **I´ve different types of content** which **maps to different .php files**. And I´m unable to determine to which .php file to route with mod_rewrite as long as I don´t use a cheat "like **/product/**chocolate-icrecream" so that I know that this URI is made for a product. But me and my customer don´t want that solution.

I´ve already started another try:

- **ALL requests** which don´t match a physical file or folder are **routed to a mapper.php** file. This file looks in the database - I´ve an index with all products, categories etc. - and gives me the correct file.
- The **mapper then loads the content via CURL** and shows it to the user

Basically I thought this was a nice idea but there are so many problems with session handling, , post data, php based redirects (header: ...) with CURL that I really plan to cancel this way etc. etc.

**So my question is:**
Has anyone of you an idea or a pattern that helps me creating the "good looking" URI´s without using a complex CURL mapper?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Mike

### **UPDATE to "Include solution":**

A good example for the "include problem":
A request for www.shop.com/cart is "rewritten" to "mapper.php". The "mapper.php" decides to include www.shop.com/shoppingcart.php.

shoppingcart.php uses smarty to display the cart. The view asks the $_SERVER variable, if the actual called file is "shoppingcart.php" to decide if the page should be shown in fullscreen mode or with additional columns.

In the "normal / direct" call $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] would be "/shopping_cart.php" which will show the fullscreen version. Going over the mapper.php with the include option would give us $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/mapper.php' which will give us the view with columns (what´s wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this simply by pointing them all to one page and then including the proper script based on the slug. For example, rewrite all requests like index.php?slug=chocolate-icrecream.

index.php

```
$resource = fetch_resource($slug);
if ($resource->slug == 'product') 
{
  include('products.php');
}
else if ($resource->type == 'category')
{
  include('category.php');
}
else
{
  include('content.php');
}
```

I don't understand why you don't want to structure your URLs like /product/chocolate-icrecream. That would be good semantic naming that is fairly consistent across the internet nowadays.

Comment: A classic include isn´t working at the moment, cause the page uses several frameworks (Smarty etc.) which for example ask for the called URL to make decisions on how to display content. If it´s an include that doesn´t work. That´s the reason why I´ve tried to solve it with CURL which also leads to massive problems with sessions, cookies and other HTTP header stuff...

So for that I´m looking for a more "elegant" solution - like a RewriteMap (which in fact I can´t use cause my customers only can access .htaccess and not the Apache vhost config).

Comment: I´ve added an update to my question above which explains the problems with an include.